# Is finding a simple path in a weighted undirected graph with maximum cost in polynomial time? Is it NP?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I need to know if it is possible to find a simple path with maximum cost in any weighted undirected graph.

I mean to find THE MOST expensive path of all for any pair of vertex.

Input: Graph G = (V,E)

Output: The cost of the most expensive path in the graph G.

Is this problem NP-Complete?, I think it is. Could you provide any reference to an article where I can review this.

Answer (score 5):

[You're not the first to think of this problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) In fact, it was the first link in the google search results.

**edit**
Guys, un-weighted graph is a special case of weighted graph: all edges have weight 1 :)

Comment: But I need to know this for a weighted graph, not the longest path in any graph. I a NO weighted graph I can clearly see why it is NP Complete.

Comment: How is that link not for a wieghted graph?  There is no longest path if there is no weight...

Comment: @Alehandro: Unweighted graphs are a special case of weighted graphs (an unweighted graph being the same as a weighted graph where every edge has the weight 1), so if a problem is NP-hard for unweighted graphs it is at least NP-hard for weighted graphs (assuming it's solvable at all for weighted graphs).

Comment: If the graph is not weighted, the longest path could mean the one with more vertex in it. I want the MOST expensive :P path, the maximum cost path.

Comment: @Alejandro For simple path, `number_of_vertexes = number_of_edges + 1`. Thus, it doesn't matter whether you count nodes or edges.

Comment: @Alejandro: If you have a graph where every edge has cost one than the maximum cost path *is* the one with most vertices in it. That's what makes it a special case.

Comment: And what if the graph has the same number of vertex and edges? (vertex = edges), is this still NP-Complete?

Comment: draw it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to traveling salesman, except your heuristic is the Max and not Min.  Read up on the traveling salesman.

The problem is NP complete because it can be derived from a problem that is already proven to be NP-Complete (Traveling salesman).  The answer is checkable in polynomial time, but an answer cannot be found in polynomial time.

Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: No, it's not. Travelling salesman is required to visit all nodes, while here it might be useful to omit some. I do agree that it's NP, though.

Comment: ah, i see he says simple path. You are right, its not travelling salesman, although it would be a good place to start.

Comment: Imagine many loops going through single central node. You can visit that node only once.

Comment: I think we would need to insist that there are no cycles, considering we could generate a path of length infinity.

Comment: It's a simple path. The restriction against cycles is already there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this problem is NP because you are asking for the *maximum* which means that you'll need to go through *all* possible paths.  The decision version of this problem ("is there a path of length *n*?") is known NP-complete (as noted above).